# How to create box in rmarkdown like show in this page

Tags: r, r-markdown

It is possible to create the box "Exercise 1"  as show in http://rpubs.com/c_bailey/538901 using r-markdown?

Comment: I think your first question is how to do it in R. It is leading you down a specific path by highlighting the word "typical", which might be defined as the average (or expected value), the most frequent, or the middle of data distribution. But until you know how to describe what you need, and then do that calculation in R, the topic of R-markdown is (in my opinion) premature.

Comment: Take a look at this repo. https://github.com/andrewpbray/oiLabs-base-R

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask how to do some CSS customization on the Rmarkdown doc like the linked one. (or, the html webpage)

Comment: thanks @TC Zhang. I found the answerd

Comment: Could you share your answer and mark it as accepted below. Other people with similar need could benefit from it.